# Using IDE on AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ide

I want to use Spyder (or similar IDE) with the Python of my AWS EC2 instance (instead of my local laptop).

What is the procedure to follow?

Now I am copy-pasting code in the console, and it is not convenient.
I use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

You can try Eclipse (its Python IDE is [PyDev](http://pydev.org/)), along with the [Remote System Explorer](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/nav/56) plugin which, I believe, is included by default.

For instructions specific to Amazon AWS, see [this blog](http://christopherickes.com/web-app-development/ssh-to-amazon-aws-with-eclipse-remote-system-explorer-rse/).

During that process, you may have to [create a new 'parent profile'](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcprofile.html), that is not mentioned in that blog.

Also, once the connection is all set up, you can create a remote file from within your local eclipse's RSE but any edits to make to a file (newly created or already existing remotely) may not be reflected in the remote system by default - they are instead stored locally under RemoteSystemsTempFiles. So, you would have to 'Export From Project' and select the locally edited file(s) that you want reflected on the remote system.